# struts2 tomcat 8 startup

Tags: configuration, struts2, migration, tomcat8

I'm running a development server with tomcat **8.5.13** and Struts **2.5.2**.

I upgraded the struts jar to **2.5.10.1**, and now I'm getting this error when the war deploys:

```
2017-04-13 06:26:59.565|DEBUG|localhost-startStop-31|Creating revision for URL: jar:file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.13/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar!/struts-default.xml
2017-04-13 06:26:59.578|DEBUG|localhost-startStop-31|Loaded action configuration from: struts-default.xml
2017-04-13 06:26:59.578|DEBUG|localhost-startStop-31|Substituting value [                 java.lang.Object,                 java.lang.Runtime,                 java.lang.System,                 java.lang.Class,                 java.lang.ClassLoader,                 java.lang.Shutdown,                 java.lang.ProcessBuilder,                 ognl.OgnlContext,                 ognl.ClassResolver,                 ognl.TypeConverter,                 ognl.MemberAccess,                 ognl.DefaultMemberAccess,                 com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.SecurityMemberAccess,                 com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext] using [com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.EnvsValueSubstitutor]
2017-04-13 06:26:59.578|DEBUG|localhost-startStop-31|Substituting value                  java.lang.Object,                 java.lang.Runtime,                 java.lang.System,                 java.lang.Class,                 java.lang.ClassLoader,                 java.lang.Shutdown,                 java.lang.ProcessBuilder,                 ognl.OgnlContext,                 ognl.ClassResolver,                 ognl.TypeConverter,                 ognl.MemberAccess,                 ognl.DefaultMemberAccess,                 com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.SecurityMemberAccess,                 com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext with proper System variable or environment variable
2017-04-12 19:59:30.243|ERROR|localhost-startStop-29|Dispatcher initialization failed
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:166) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrLookup.copyProperties(StrLookup.java:73) ~[commons-lang3-3.4.jar:3.4]
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrLookup.systemPropertiesLookup(StrLookup.java:99) ~[commons-lang3-3.4.jar:3.4]
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor.replaceSystemProperties(StrSubstitutor.java:231) ~[commons-lang3-3.4.jar:3.4]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.EnvsValueSubstitutor.substitute(EnvsValueSubstitutor.java:39) ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:282) ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
        at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:98) ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:165) ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67) ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:906) ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445) ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:486) [struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:75) [struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:63) [struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4590) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5233) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_101]
```

I thought this was resolved, because when I restarted Tomcat everything worked fine.  However, when I just move a new WAR without restarting, I still sometimes (but not every time) get this error.  Whenever I restart Tomcat, the filter starts normally.  The constants in my struts.xml are:

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=",html" />
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="css_xhtml" />
```

Here are the JARs in the library under WEB-INF/lib

```
activation-1.1.jar
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.119.jar
aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.119.jar
aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.119.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar
commonj.sdo-2.1.1.jar
commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
commons-codec-1.9.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-lang3-3.4.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
commons-validator-1.6.jar
eclipselink-2.6.4.jar
freemarker-2.3.23.jar
hamcrest-core-1.1.jar
httpclient-4.5.3.jar
httpcore-4.4.6.jar
ion-java-1.0.2.jar
jackson-annotations-2.6.6.jar
jackson-core-2.6.6.jar
jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar
jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.6.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
javax.json-1.0.4.jar
javax.persistence-2.1.1.jar
jaxwsapi-1.2.0.jar
jmespath-java-1.11.119.jar
joda-time-2.8.1.jar
json-simple-1.1.1.jar
junit-4.10.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
log4j-api-2.7.jar
log4j-core-2.7.jar
mail-1.4.7.jar
mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar
ognl-3.1.12.jar
org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar
poi-3.13.jar
quartz-2.2.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

Comment: Show `constants` in the struts.xml file.

Comment: Please provide files added in lib folder Richard

Comment: The constants and the lib jars have both been added to the question.  Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: @RichardH You have some trouble with system properties. Do you remove/modify them? Try with `commons-lang3-3.5.jar`, see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven, or check manually that the *other* needed and related libraries are aligned.

Struts 2.5.10.1 uses different libraries versions from Struts 2.5.2.

You can find them in the [official pom.xml on Github](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/pom.xml):

```xml
<struts2.springPlatformVersion>4.1.6.RELEASE</struts2.springPlatformVersion>
<ognl.version>3.1.12</ognl.version>
<asm.version>5.1</asm.version>
<tiles.version>3.0.7</tiles.version>
<tiles-request.version>1.0.6</tiles-request.version>
<log4j2.version>2.8</log4j2.version>
```

Those are for the current version, which is 2.5.11-SNAPSHOT.

[Browsing the History](https://github.com/apache/struts/commits/master/pom.xml), you can see that **2.5.10.1** has **log4j 2.7** instead of 2.8, (and commons-lang3 3.4 instead of 3.5, but just use the newest).

Carefully align the versions of your libraries and come back if you still have problems, posting a detailed list of the libraries you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure exactly what was going on with this, but I restarted Tomcat and everything is working fine now.  Before that, I was just reloading the WAR files.

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Used these jars versions for struts 2.5.12 with tomcat 8.5.16 and Eclipse Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0) and they worked just fine.

- commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar
- commons-io-2.4.jar
- commons-lang3-3.6.jar
- freemarker-2.3.23.jar
- javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
- log4j-api-2.8.2.jar
- log4j-core-2.8.2.jar
- ognl-3.1.12.jar
- struts2-core-2.5.12.jar

Hopefully this alignment of jars versions helps.